# How to select multiple objects with different appearance in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

Say I want to select e.g. all red diamonds AND all text in the following image. What should I do?

I can select all red diamonds by choosing one, then Select --> Same --> Appearance. I can also select all text by Select --> Object --> Text Objects. But how can I select both?

p.s. I'm using Adobe Illustrator CS6 in Mac OS.

Thanks,

-Xianjun

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, select the red diamonds using Select>Same>Fill color, Then press Ctrl G to group them.

Then do the same with the text, Select>object>text objects, and also group the text elements.

Then whilst holding shift, Select both groups by clicking one of each type and you're good to go.

You can also save the selections you make if you use them often within the same document by going to Select>Save Selection...

Comment: Thank you, James. It is my working solution for now. Any way to select both without grouping them first?

Comment: Not that i know of in cs6.